# How to construct the map which verifies that the tensor product of algebras is the fibered coproduct using universal properties?

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products, universal-property

Let $A \rightarrow B$ and $A \rightarrow C$ be commutative ring morphisms. I am trying to verify the universal property of the fibered coproduct for the ring $B \otimes_A C$ with maps $i_B: B \rightarrow B \otimes_A C$ and $i_C: C \rightarrow B \otimes_A C$ given by $b \mapsto b \otimes 1$ and $c \mapsto 1 \otimes c$ respectively.

So let $W$ be a ring such that we have ring morphisms $f_B: B \rightarrow W$ and $f_C: C \rightarrow W$. What I want to see is that there exists a unique map $f: B \otimes_A C \rightarrow W$ with the properties that $i_B \circ f = f_B $ and $i_C \circ f = f_C$.

Now to obtain $f$, the only way I can see is to apply the universal property of the tensor product. For this, I need an $A$-bilinear map $B \times C \rightarrow W$. The problem is that I don't see how to fabricate such a map from the maps $f_B: B \rightarrow W$ and $f_C: C \rightarrow W$. Rather, the setup allows me to find a map from the coproduct of $B$ and $C$, which at least in $Set$ is  the disjoint union, so I don't see how that is useful.

Comment: The simplest of such bilinear maps is $(b,c)\mapsto f_B(b)f_C(c).$

Comment: @Acrobatic Can this be characterised by any universal property, or do I have to provide an elementwise definition?

Comment: It's not an elementwise definition of a map on the tensor product, it is a bilinear map and you apply the universal property of the tensor product to produce a map on the tensor product. The point is that if $W$ is a ring admitting morphisms from $B$ and $C$ then you must be able to *multiply elements of $B$ by elements of $C$ in $W$*; that's where this map comes from.

Comment: The list of what you have to show: The induced morphism $f: B\otimes_A C\to W$ is a morphism of $A$-algebras. $f$ verifies the universal property of coproduct. (Commutativity of the diagram can be shown elementwise. The uniqueness can be shown by the universal property of tensor product; The bilinear map above is the only one whose induced morphism $B\otimes_A C \to W$ makes the diagram associated to coproduct commutative.)